# What is the fastest way to know if a letter exists in a Character collection

Tags: java

1. Should I define a hashmap with something like "A" , new Character("A")
2. should I use something like a sorted list ? or cast it into an int?
3. simple list? (that doesnt seem too efficient )

I need a fast retrieving - when I ask if the Char exists.
adding time is almost none important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we're talking about a `Collection`: It depends on the collection *type*. A `HashSet` offers the best performance for `contains` operations, which is O(1).

```
Set<Character> chars = new HashSet<Character>();
chars.add(new Character('A'));    
chars.add(new Character('B'));
chars.add(new Character('C'));

if (chars.contains('A'))
  System.out.println("Lightning fast answer: TRUE");
```

Answer (score 1):

A `char` is an unsigned 16-bit value and can take on only 65,536 values. Since you talk about existence, I am kind of assuming you have a `Set` and not a general `Collection`. Use a `BitSet` to represent this set; add and check the existence of a `char` as if it is an integer value (because it is). This is the fastest I can imagine, will be faster for sure than a regular `HashSet of`Character`, and it takes just 8K of memory.

Comment: Well currently the existing code has a list<charatcters>. it was written in generics. I wanted to improve  this part and thought about SortedList<Carracter>.  Also, I dont ever have collisions. a letter appears only once.

Comment: Collisions don't refer to collisions of characters, but to collisions under the hood of a hash. A hash stores items in slots, and if it finds a slot already filled, it has to deal with it somehow. Too many hash collisions can slow it down dramatically.

Comment: No, also finding the slot to look for an element for must take exactly the same steps (slot hops) as if you were inserting. Otherwise you might not succeed finding an item that is actually there. See [Wikipedia on collisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't process the whole range of unicode characters, a simple (bit/bool) array should be reasonably fast. Compared to a hash you won't have to worry about collisions, too.

Comment: Even if you process the whole range, the memory is requirement is acceptable.

Comment: please elaborate. A hash will be heavy on the inserts. but wouldn't it be faster on the retrieving? would a sorted array not be faster than a simple array ?

Comment: For indexing into an array you know the starting point in memory and the position within the array, so it's a simple addition behind the scenes. A hash uses a slightly more complicated way to know where to look—but there might be collisions and then it takes longer. Sorting is not necessary because you know exactly where to look in the array (implicitly sorted by code position).

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of your alphabet? 
If it is small and all characters are ASCII characters you can use array.

```
boolean[] chars;
chars['A'] = true;
```